# Show Current Database Value as Default in Dropdown

Tags: javascript

I have a dropdown that a selection produces another dropdown with values. All of this writes to the database correctly. I can't figure out how to show the current database value (ie the last value submitted) to show up in the 'second' drop down ('first' dropdown works fine in recalling the database information). So when I select 'Masking Available' I would like that to show up when I open the webpage next time.

```
function configureDropDownLists(main, second) {
    var masking1e = new Array('', 'Masking Available');
    var permissivemode1e = new Array('', 'Permissive Mode Enabled');

    switch (main.value) {
        case 'Masking':
            document.getElementById(second).options.length = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < masking1e.length; i++) {
                createOption(document.getElementById(second), masking1e[i], masking1e[i]);
            }
            break;
        case 'Permissive Mode':
            document.getElementById(second).options.length = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < permissivemode1e.length; i++) {
                createOption(document.getElementById(second), permissivemode1e[i], permissivemode1e[i]);
            }
            break;

        default:
            document.getElementById(second).options.length = 0;
            break;
    }

}

function createOption(first, text, value) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = value;
    opt.text = text;
    first.options.add(opt);
}
```

```
<select name="first"  id="first" onchange="configureDropDownLists(this,'second')">
    <option value="">Please Select Accommodation</option>
    <option value="Masking" <?php if ($first== "Masking"){ echo "SELECTED"; } ?>>Masking</option>
    <option value="Permissive Mode" <?php if ($first== "Permissive Mode"){ echo "SELECTED"; } ?>>Permissive Mode</option>
</select>
</br>
<select name="second" id="second">
</select>
```